# pickle cython class

Tags: python, class, pickle, cython, reduce

I have to save and load a cython class instance.
My cython class is this plus several methods:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython    
cdef class Perceptron_avg_my:
    cdef int wlen,freePos
    cdef np.ndarray w,wtot,wac,wtotc #np.ndarray[np.int32_t]
    cdef np.ndarray wmean  #np.ndarray[np.float32_t]    
    cdef public dict fpos    

    def __cinit__(self,np.int64_t wlen=4*10**7):
        self.fpos= dict()
        self.freePos=1
        self.wlen=wlen
        self.w=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
        self.wtot=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
        self.wac=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
        self.wtotc=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
        self.wmean=np.zeros(wlen,np.float32)

    cpdef evaluate_noavg(self,list f):
        cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t] w = self.w
        cdef dict fpos = self.fpos        
        cdef bytes ff
        cdef int i
        cdef long int score=0

        for ff in f:
            i=fpos.get(ff,0)  
            if i != 0: 
                score += w[i]
        return score
```

I was thinking to use the cPickle module.
I understand that I have to implement a __reduce__(self) method but I have some problem to find an example and to understand well the documentation

I tried to add something like this to Perceptron_avg_my but not works:

```
    def rebuild(self,l):
        self.fpos=l[0]
        self.freePos=l[1]

    def __reduce__(self):
        #print 'reduce call'
        return (Perceptron_avg_my.rebuild,(self.fpos,self.freePos))
```

any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: helpful discussion here as well: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8376/pickling-extension-classes/

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if you found it, but the official Python documentation has [a section on pickling extension types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) (unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a Python 3 version of this doc, but it works the same in Python 3).

I think you have three problems here.  Firstly, the function returned by `__reduce__` is supposed to create a new object from scratch and return it, whereas your `rebuild` function just sets some attributes.  Secondly, the tuple returned by `__reduce__` must itself be picklable, and as a method, `Perceptron_avg_my.rebuild` is not picklable (I think this is expected to be fixed in python 3.3 or 3.4).  Instead, you could turn it into a module-level function.  Finally, the arguments `(self.fpos,self.freePos)` are passed to `rebuild` individually - you don't have to unpack the tuple yourself.

The following seems to work for me (though you probably want to store the values of the other attributes too, otherwise they will just have the initial values set by `__init__`):

```
#inside the class definition
def __reduce__(self):
    return (rebuild, (self.wlen, self.fpos, self.freePos))

#standalone function
def rebuild(wlen, fpos, freePos):
    p = Perceptron_avg_my(wlen)
    p.fpos = fpos
    p.freePos = freePos
    return p
```

Comment: thank you James and sorry if I reply just now!!!
I think that there is also another problem: the function returned by \__reduce__ can't be in the cython module (I honestly don't understand why). I will add an answer with a workaround that works to me... but I don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: That's odd: it works for me when it's defined inside the module.  You didn't accidentally use `cdef` instead of `def` to define the function, did you?  Or maybe we are just using different versions of cython or python (I tried it with python 3.2.3 / cython 0.17, and python 2.7.2 / cython 0.15.1).

Comment: I use python 2.7.3 / cython 0.17.

Comment: If I put the cython module in a subpackage **./ml/** your solution doesn't work:
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in function rebuild_perceptron>: import of module perceptron failed.


I use in my main.py **from ml.perceptron import Perceptron**. My ./ml/__init__.py is empty. Is there something wrong in my subpackage ?

Comment: works great, thanks the document itself is not as concise and dives into many corner cases without a simple example.

Answer (score 6):

As of Cython 0.26 (released July 2017), implementing the pickle protocol is no longer necessary. All cdef classes that do not contain pointers or unions can automatically be pickled. For classes containing structs automatic pickling is disabled by default, due to (among other reasons) high code overhead. Automatic pickling can be enabled for classes with structs by using the `@cython.auto_pickle(True)` decorator.

More information can be found in the [changelog](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#026-2017-07-19) and on [the website of Stefan Behnel](http://blog.behnel.de/posts/whats-new-in-cython-026.html).

Comment: Glad to see the new release! However I still had to implement my own pickling mechanism b/c `TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__`

Comment: What about cdef classes that do contain pointers?

Comment: @ibarrond I have not been following Cython development that close recently. I don't know if this would work or what you would have to do to make it work. If you find out, please let us know ;)

Answer (score 3):

I used this workaround that works but I am not sure that it is the best solution.

I created a new support file to declare the function called by reduce (if I put it in the cython module it not works):

```
#perceptron_supp.py

from perceptron import Perceptron

def rebuild_perceptron(wlen,freePos,fpos,w,nw_avg,wtot_avg,wsup_avg,wmean_avg,wtot_my,wac_my,wtotc_my,wmean_my):
    return Perceptron(wlen,True,freePos,fpos,w,nw_avg,wtot_avg,wsup_avg,wmean_avg,wtot_my,wac_my,wtotc_my,wmean_my)
```

and then I import this function in cython module:

```
#perceptron.pyx

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

#added
from perceptron_supp import rebuild_perceptron

cdef class Perceptron:
    cdef int wlen,freePos
    cdef dict fpos

    cdef np.ndarray w #np.ndarray[np.int32_t]

    cdef int nw_avg
    cdef np.ndarray wtot_avg,wsup_avg #np.ndarray[np.int32_t]
    cdef np.ndarray wmean_avg  #np.ndarray[np.float64_t]

    cdef np.ndarray wtot_my,wac_my,wtotc_my #np.ndarray[np.int32_t]
    cdef np.ndarray wmean_my  #np.ndarray[np.float64_t]

    def __cinit__(self,int wlen=4*10**7,setValues=False,freePos=0,fpos=0,w=0,nw_avg=0,wtot_avg=0,wsup_avg=0,wmean_avg=0,wtot_my=0,wac_my=0,wtotc_my=0,wmean_my=0):
        if not setValues:            
            self.wlen=wlen
            self.freePos=1
            self.fpos= dict()

            self.w=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)

            self.nw_avg=1
            self.wtot_avg=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)            
            self.wsup_avg=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
            self.wmean_avg=np.zeros(wlen,np.float64)

            self.wtot_my=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)    
            self.wac_my=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
            self.wtotc_my=np.zeros(wlen,np.int32)
            self.wmean_my=np.zeros(wlen,np.float64)
        else:           
            self.wlen=wlen
            self.freePos=freePos
            self.fpos=fpos

            self.w=w

            self.nw_avg=nw_avg
            self.wtot_avg=wtot_avg
            self.wsup_avg=wsup_avg
            self.wmean_avg=wmean_avg

            self.wtot_my=wtot_my
            self.wac_my=wac_my
            self.wtotc_my=wtotc_my
            self.wmean_my=wmean_my

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (rebuild_perceptron,(self.wlen,self.freePos,self.fpos,self.w,self.nw_avg,self.wtot_avg,self.wsup_avg,self.wmean_avg,self.wtot_my,self.wac_my,self.wtotc_my,self.wmean_my))
```

when I use my perceptron module I have just to do: from perceptron import Perceptron and now I can do cPyckle.dump or cPickle.load when I need.

If somebody has a better solution thanks a lot!!!